# AutoMapper - Flattening/Unflattening to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I want to flatten my entity framework model data to dto for my ASP.NET Core REST Web Service.

My entity classes (simplified) look like:

```
public class DeliveryNoteEntity
{
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
    public int NotMapped { get; set; }
    public List<DeliveryNoteSignature> Signatures { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryNoteSignature
{
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    public SignedByRole SignedBy { get; set; }
}

public enum SignedByRole
{
    Driver = 1,
    Recipient = 2
}
```

My dto looks like

```
public class DeliveryNoteDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }
    public string DriverSignature { get; set; }
    public string RecipientSignature { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can fill my entity like this

```
var sourceEntity = new DeliveryNoteEntity
{
    VehicleNo = "VehicleNo20",
    Signatures = new List<DeliveryNoteSignature> { new DeliveryNoteSignature { Signature = "Driver Mr. Pitz", SignedBy = SignedByRole.Driver} }
};
```

and map to a dto:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DeliveryNoteEntity, DeliveryNoteDto>()
                                    .ForMember(dest => dest.DriverSignature, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Signatures
                                                                                                          .Where(x => x.SignedBy == SignedByRole.Driver)
                                                                                                          .Select(x => x.Signature)
                                                                                                          .FirstOrDefault()))
                                    .ForMember(dest => dest.RecipientSignature, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Signatures
                                                                                                             .Where(x => x.SignedBy == SignedByRole.Recipient)
                                                                                                             .Select(x => x.Signature)
                                                                                                             .FirstOrDefault()))
                                    .ReverseMap()
                                    );
var dto = Mapper.Map<DeliveryNoteDto>(sourceEntity);
```

So my question is: how can I do a reverse mapping from dto to entity when it comes back to my service? So by hand I would do something like this:

```
var entityToSave = new DeliveryNoteEntity()
{
    VehicleNo = dto.VehicleNo,
    Signatures = new List<DeliveryNoteSignature>
    {
         new DeliveryNoteSignature {SignedBy = SignedByRole.Driver, Signature = dto.DriverSignature},
         new DeliveryNoteSignature {SignedBy = SignedByRole.Recipient, Signature = dto.RecipientSignature}
    }
};
```

It there any way to do it with AutoMapper?

**EDIT**: my real question is how can I do a mapping from XXXSignature properties in my dto to a list in my entity?

Comment: I dunno how often I have to tell the people: do **NOT** map DTOs back to Entities. NEVER. AutoMapper was not made for this case and in 98% of all cases it won't work very well with ORMs. AutoMapper (also stated by the Author of Automapper) is meant to map from Entities/Domain to DTOs, ViewModels. See https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/. If you have desire to map Dtos to Entities via automapper, your design is flawed. Or you never worked with ORMs that track entities (EF/EF Core) and don't know yet what kind of troubles you are getting in

Comment: You may wanna have a read on [this blog post](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/)

Comment: @Tseng but it was in 2009, and actually they have two way mapping http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html How would you update your EF Core entity from dto?

Comment: Same way you do it w/o AutoMapper. Only use AutoMapper for Entity (or domain Model) -> DTO/ViewModel mapping. When you start get page long AutoMapper configuration code, you know you're in a use case automapper was not meant to. Intension of Automapper is automatically (D'oh :P) map the entities and customize it in some rare cases. When you have to map most or all models via the mapping configuration, you know its wrong

Comment: On top of that, if you read the 2nd post, you'll end up having your code outside of your business layer and hidden in some obscure AutoMapper configs

Comment: @Tseng yes I read the second post, and it sounds reasonable to me. I do not like hidden logic at all, so if config gets complicated I prefer to implement this part as a code, not at least because it easier for my teammates to get a clue what happens there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing that by code, so I can clearly detect and define add, delete and update operations. So I use AutoMapper only one way: entity -> dto.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AutoMapper's naming convention, ReverseMap is also done for you.

```
class CustomerClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}

class MainClass
{
     public CustomerClass Customer {get; set;}
}
```

---

```
class MainClassDto
{
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    public string CustomerSurname {get; set;}

}
```

For this example you do not need to make any configuration for mapping and/or reverse mapping. AutoMapper handles it with its default configuration

Comment: My question was mostly about how to map a list to flat properties, Signatures -> DriverSignature and RecipientSignature and back.